# Ruby enumerator in Rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
<ul>
<% for file in @files %>
 <li><%= file %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

output :

file1

file2

but if i want to use enumerator :

```
<% @files.each{|file| file} %>
```

output :  ['file1', 'file2']

I can not get the output as a <\li> list.

My question is is it possible to get the list output using enumeration? if so how??
I am a beginner at rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of one liner, you could do:

```
<%=raw @files.map {|file| content_tag(:li, file)}.join %>

#mix
<% @files.each do |file| %> <%= content_tag(:li, file) %> <% end %>
```

But ***really***, **don't**!

Comment: +1 from me and yes, OP, don't do this for the sake of other devs that may see your code.

Comment: Thanks I have the answer now. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
<% @files.each do |file| %>
  <li><%= file %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: but i wanted to avoid using "do" ,is it possible to use a block rather than do loop?

Comment: you can replace `do` with `{` and `end` with `}`. `do end` === `{ }`, for the most part.

Comment: @files.each{|file| file } 
in erb file how should i write this ?

Comment: @sunny1304 so you really just want it on one line, huh?

Comment: @sunny1304, may I ask why do you want to avoid do?

Comment: no ,no i am not that lazy, i just want to know if it is even possible,
i just cant get it off my mind .

Comment: using erb you can start <% and put as many ruby code as you want and finish with a %>.. you don't have to put it on the same line